# How to convert mathematical numbers into floats

Tags: python, math

In python, is there a way or even build in Function to convert a string into a float? Specifically:`+1.488763E+01` into `14.88763` ?

Comment: You're confusing string representation with internal representation.

Comment: Do you mean, can you convert `'+1.488763E+01'` to `'14.88763'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have is a valid `float` literal. Convert it to a `float`, then convert the result back to a `str`

```
>>> '{:f}'.format(float('+1.488763E+01'))
'14.887630'
```

The `format` method is used to force the value to be represented as a fixed-point value, rather than in exponential notation. For example,

```
>>> str(float('1e20'))
'1e+20'
>>> '{:f}'.format(float('1e20'))
'100000000000000000000.000000'
```

Answer (score 0):

Python does this conversion automatically. Just try it.

```
a = +1.488763E+01
print(a)
    14.88763
```

Answer (score 0):

It’s a decimal, it already is a float. Though if you print it, python will automatically put it in the format you want.
As long as you don’t have it as a string, it’ll be in the format you want it.

```
a = +1.488763E+01
```

print(a)
    14.88763

Comment: yes I know, but i have a csv with values like this, so i need to convert them somehow

Comment: @67527845 if you just print it, python should automatically convert it into that format you want, as shown by my includes code

Comment: @67527845 have you tried float (“whatever variable the number is stored as”) ? To change it to a float?

Answer (score 0):

You can use float() function

```
float(a)
```